# Updating Jenkins on Centos

Tags: jenkins, centos, centos7

I'm trying to update `Jenkins` on `Centos7`

When I run `service Jenkins status` command I can see that Jenkins is active.

When I try to connect to Jenkins using the browser I'm getting this message:

> refused to connect to http://*****:8080.

I have followed the following steps but it's not working:

1) Run `service Jenkins stop` command.

2) Replaced `Jenkins.war` with the new one.

3) Run `service Jenkins start` command.

Comment: Use `ps` to confirm that the process has actually stopped / started.

Comment: Is your URL http://*****:8080 or http://*****:8080/jenkins?

Comment: after starting jenkins service i can see that it's really running, when i write ps -ef|grep jenkins i can see the process.

Comment: it's http://******:8080

Comment: does i have to wait a several minutes till i can load jenkins using browser ?

Comment: Check the log to see if Jenkins is running.

Comment: how can i check the log

Comment: jenkins process has been stopped suddenly, it is not running now. how to run it manually ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111333/discussion-between-roni-and-luka5z).

Comment: Why did you decide to replace the `jenkins.war` manually?  Jenkins has an in-place upgrade option under _Manage Jenkins_ (for the latest version, at least).

Comment: i don't have this option in jenkins, because that i choose to change it manutally

Answer (score 26):

i update it using this command :

```
yum update jenkins
```

it's working well

Comment: Is it safe to simply do " yum update jenkins "  without stopping Jenkins (with " service Jenkins stop ") ?

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me on RedHat distribution:

```
sudo service jenkins stop
yum update jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: If you got error `Public key for jenkins-xx.noarch.rpm is not installed`, you may use:  
`sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo`  
`sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key`  
More information [here](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/).